# Get a list/vector of values from a data.frame by passing a list/vector of indices

Tags: r, dataframe

```
indices <- c(2,5,9)
```

customer is a data.frame.

I want a list of values from column 2 of customer in the index position of indices.

```
names <- as.list(customer[,2] << indices)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a simple extract from the data frame.  Try:

```
customer[indices, 2]
```